# Notifing email text format issue

Tags: 7, notifications

I installed the Subscription module on my site to get forum notifications.
If a user comments on a forum topic, the subscriber gets a notification saying:

> There is a new forum topic “forum topic test” added by sai.

This happens for every comment of the forum post. I need a new comment in place of a new forum topic.

Any solution for this?

Comment: What the difference between this question and your prior question at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/225091/ ? Also, what do you mean by "***I need a new comment in place of a new forum topic.***"? Could it be that you mean something like "I want the subscriber to get a notification saying **There is a new comment about 'forum topic test' added by sai**"? Ps: how about using the "Message" module instead of the "Subscription" module?

Comment: Hi Pierre.Vriens, I am getting the same subjecting for both new posting and comments on the old posting also.